# In kotlin how can I access this function from enum class in another class?

Tags: java, kotlin, oop, libgdx

To facilitate navigation between screens in my game I created this class

```
enum class ScreenEnum {
    MAIN_MENU {
        fun getScreen(): BaseScreen {
            return MenuScreen()
        }
    },
    GAME {
        fun getScreen(): BaseScreen {
            return GameScreen()
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't know how I can access these methods from another class in kotlin, did I do something wrong when creating the enum class? Thanks in advance if you can help me.

```
class Game() : BaseGame() {
    override fun create() {
       super.create()
       // -> Here is where I am trying to access the getScreen method
       // ScreenEnum.MAIN_MENU
    }
}
```

I tried to access from a java class but without success

Comment: I would rename those functions to something like `generateNewScreen()`, since by convention `getScreen()` on an enum implies it returns the same instance each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make it a shared abstract method:

```
enum class ScreenEnum {
    MAIN_MENU {
        override fun getScreen(): BaseScreen {
            return MenuScreen()
        }
    },
    GAME {
        override fun getScreen(): BaseScreen {
            return GameScreen()
        }
    };

    abstract fun getScreen(): BaseScreen
}
```